# Problems escaping spaces in string variable with grep command and SU

Tags: terminal, bash, dock, zsh, ventura

macOS Ventura is apparently no longer letting us set the default Dock application items from root (command silently fails), so we are having to run in the user's space from our MDM script. Unfortunately, this means I have to chain a grep command with SU which is causing me all sorts of problems for items that have spaces:

zsh for the environment, other logic to set $current_user that's not relevant removed.

```
    printf '%s%s%s%s%s' \
           '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict>' \
           '<key>_CFURLString</key><string>' \
           "$1" \
           '</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer>' \
           '</dict></dict></dict>'
}

for dockItem in {/Applications/{"Google Chrome","Slack","zoom.us"}.app,"Done"}; do
    echo $dockItem
    if [[ -e "$dockItem" ]]; then
        if ! [[ $dockItem == "Done" ]]; then
            # Does not actually work, nor does setting GREP_ARRAY=(-q "$dockItem") with grep "${GREP_ARRAY[@]}"
            # does not properly escape the path when executed "Chrome.app does not exist"
            EscapedPath=$( echo "$dockItem" | sed 's/ /\\ /g' )
            if (/usr/bin/su - "${current_user}" -c "defaults read com.apple.dock persistent-apps | /usr/bin/grep -q $EscapedPath"); then
                printf '%s\n' 'Dock icon already found.'
            else
                printf '%s\n' 'Setting up Dock icons...'
                /usr/bin/su - "${current_user}" -c "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '$(__dock_item $dockItem)'"
            fi
        fi
    else
        printf '%s\n' 'Restarting Dock...'
        killall Dock
    fi
done
```

Any time it tries to process "Google Chrome" the grep command fails and the application is pinned to the dock again, creating an endless cycle of copies of Chrome being added.

I've tried multiple methods to escape $dockItem, and converting it to an array, but it fails to recognize the complete string in Ventura's zsh shell.

```
if (/usr/bin/su - "${current_user}" -c "defaults read com.apple.dock persistent-apps | /usr/bin/grep -q '$dockItem'"); then
```

Is not properly escaped when executed either.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only reason why you fiddle with the white space inside dockItem, is that your use of `su -c` involves evaluating the string, thereby breaking on white space, I would do here the following thumb trick:

Place `dockItem` into the environment:

```
export dockItem
```

Then do any variable expansion inside the child process **created** by `su`, instead of in the parent process which **runs** `su`:

```
if /usr/bin/su - $current_user -c 'defaults read com.apple.dock persistent-apps | /usr/bin/grep -q $dockItem'
then
```

This assumes that `su` also runs a zsh (which I guess is true on the Mac). If this is not the case you have to quote the variable to prevent word splitting:

```
if /usr/bin/su - $current_user -c 'defaults read com.apple.dock persistent-apps | /usr/bin/grep -q "$dockItem"'
then
```